# How to use numpy to add a value by iterating the other values from another array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays. I want to access just the first index of array1 and add it to the values of array2. How can I use Numpy for this? I apologize as I cannot phrase my question correctly.

Here is an updated example: 10 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 which results to 25.

```
array1 = [10,11,12] 
array2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I would like to store each result in a third array.

```
array3 = [11,13,16,20,25]
```

Comment: What you want is not very clear for me. There is no 13, 16 or 30 in the example arrays. Do you want to do something like `array1 + array2[0:array1.size]` ?

Comment: no just the first index not the whole array1

Comment: Please update your example with the comment you made in the answer below.

Comment: `array1[0] + np.cumsum(array2)` in the current [state](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74507529/4) of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need numpy, just with for loop, code could look like this :

```py
array1 = [10, 11, 12]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
s = 0
sumArray = []
for i in range(0, len(array1)):
    s += array1[i]
    for j in range(0, len(array2)):
        s += array2[j]
    sumArray.append(s)
    s = 0
print(sumArray)
# in one line of code
print([array1[i] + sum(array2) for i in range(0, len(array1))])
# output [25, 26, 27]
# I hope this is what you want !
```

Comment: Hi sorry I made a typo on the example basically what I would like is to iterate the first index on the first array which is 10 and add it over to all values so it's something like 10 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 which results to 25.

Comment: ah ok I change my code rigth now !

Comment: I changed my code, I hope this is what you want !

Comment: OP specifically asks "How can I use numpy for this?" in the question and title.

Comment: btw, both solutions are unnecessarily O(n*m), while a trivial solution would be O(n)+O(m). `array1 + np.sum(array2)` is several orders of magnitude faster for larger arrays.